# Bad DNS records pointing to root servers

Tags: networking, dns, root

I noticed today that there are 4 suspicious-looking DNS A-records pointing to the ISI root server at `192.228.79.201` (`b.root-servers.net`), namely:

- [`www.`]`allabouttheword.com`: `a.gtld-servers.net` says `ns7[12].domaincontrol.com` (`216.69.185.46`, `208.109.255.46`) are authoritative, and both those servers return A-records for `allabouttheword.com` and `www.allabouttheword.com` pointing to `192.228.79.201`. The SOA serial is `2011050701`, suggesting it's been this way a long time;
- [`mail.`]`stpmz.ru`: `b.dns.ripn.net` says `ns[12].reg.ru` (`194.58.116.53`, `194.58.116.54`) are authoritative, and both those servers return A-records for `stpmz.ru` and `mail.stpmz.ru` pointing to `192.228.79.201`. The serial number on the SOA records (`1439200731`) does not seem to be in the normal format, so it's not clear how old they are.

I started to report the issue to Verisign, who appears to at least have some part in managing DNS, but first thought I'd see if the problem was more widespread, finding that other root servers also have incorrect-looking references to them:

- `198.41.0.4` (`a.root-servers.net`): `atctk.com` (also points to `202.12.27.33` (`m.root-servers.net`)), `www.ot-servers.net`;
- `192.33.4.12` (`c.root-servers.net`): `scarecrowqc.com`, `www.xn--kenstorkkken-2jb.com`;
- `192.5.5.241` (`f.root-servers.net`): `555xt.meibu.com`, `mstsc.555xt.com`, `unravelling.nl`;
- etc.

It probably doesn't result in much spurious traffic, since I doubt those domains are active, or someone would have fixed them, since they don't point to the right place.

I'll note that the `in-addr.arpa` servers do not seem to have corresponding PTR records: `209.112.113.33` (`a.verisigndns.com`), authoritative for `0.41.198.in-addr.arpa`, reports `4.0.41.198.in-addr.arpa name = a.root-servers.net` only.

Should these be reported to the sources of the bad records, or Verisign (apparently the current manager of the top of the DNS), or is it a non-issue?

Comment: Just how are you finding these, anyway?

Comment: A lookup of 192.228.79.201 at Robtex.com, though there are other sites like it, who process the various DNS and routing databases in interesting ways. The rest of the investigation, I did with nslookup, just to ensure it wasn't something wrong at Robtex.

Answer (score 1):

Some people are publishing DNS info that points to Verisign's IP addresses?  That's a non-issue.  If I am running a DNS server (and, in fact, I am), I can point an "A" Resource Record to any IPv4 address I want.  That isn't anything that Verisign can control, so reporting it to them will not help at all.  If there's anyone to report the "problem" to, it would be the person who is running the authoritative DNS server.  (To find out who is running it, use the search box in the upper-right corner of ARIN WHOIS; that might be helpful.)  However, that person may be free to just ignore the report, because, from what I'm understanding, it really isn't an actual problem of any kind.

Comment: Whoever set up the zone that way also obviously *did* set up the zone that way. They will fix it when they notice that their host name isn't working. Until then, well... to start with, only one of the root name servers [are not distributed using anycast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_DNS_servers#Root_server_addresses), and they are dimensioned for pretty heavy loads; for example, [a.root-servers.net sees upwards of six billion queries per day](http://a.root-servers.org/metrics.html).